# Batch file that runs impdp through network link keeps failing

Tags: oracle, batch-file, datapump, oracle12.1

I have been writing a batch file that runs an impdp job through a network link.

```
@echo off

set server=%1
set schema=%2
set site=%3
set local_schema=%site%_SYNC

sqlplus -S sync_sites/password @C:\expdir\drop_create_user_oracle.sql %server% %schema% %site% %local_schema%

C:\app\Oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\BIN\impdp %local_schema%/password remap_schema=%schema%:%local_schema% NETWORK_LINK=%1 CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY EXCLUDE=STATISTICS VERSION=12.1
```

The dblink that was created through the SQL file is working well, as I can manually query through it.
The problem is that when I run the batch, I keep getting the same errors:

```
Import: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Wed Aug 24 18:41:47 2022

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options
ORA-39006: internal error
ORA-39113: Unable to determine database version
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00352: Unable to access another database 'WPP_TEST'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SYS@WPP_TEST' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

ORA-39097: Data Pump job encountered unexpected error -6550
```

I tried to find a solution online and failed to do so.
I tried to change the version, run it without a version, change many parameters in the impdp code but got the same results.
Could you please shed light on this? Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you testing the DB link as yourself, or as the user the import is run as?

Comment: @AlexPoole I tested the dblink both from the same user (the value that is sent to %local_schema%) and from another schema on the same database.

Comment: Does the user on the remote DB have execute permission on the SYS.DBMS_UTILITY package? If you have access to My Oracle Support, look at doc ID 2607463.1, which seems to be what you are seeing.

Comment: I did a little googling. `http://chandu208.blogspot.com/2017/04/ora-39113-unable-to-determine-database.html` might assist.

Comment: @Magoo thanks! but they suggest that the dblink should be public, and the one I create is public.

Comment: @AlexPoole unfortunately I don't have access to oracle support. And even more unfortunate is that I don't know how to check (and correct if needed) the SYS.DBMS_UTILITY package issue.
Could you please write the highlights?

Comment: You can check by connecting directly to the remote database in SQL\Plus or SQL Developer, as that user, and seeing if you can `describe sys.dbms_utility`. If not then a DBA on that remote database would need to grant privileges on it.

Comment: @AlexPoole apparently there were a few parameters in the impdp code that were wrongly specified. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AlexPoole FYI the problem was the definition of the dblink - apparently for a regular query from the editor, it is enough to define the linked DB by the instance name.
However, for a datapump job one needs to state all the parameters - server, port, service.